# Database design for a customer and payment system

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, table

I need help with database schema design.

#### Business rules

- We have users, each user can have listings.
- Each listing has one or more license.
- There are *n* type of licenses (products)
- Each listing can have only one product per type

#### Current tables arrangement

I have a `product` table (type, price, duration, recurring, manual). Each product has price, duration, if it is recurring or one time of, if payment type will be manual or automatic and a type.

The `business_product` table stores all assigned products to listing, start time, end time, `business_product_status` enum('paid','canceled', 'processing').

The `user_product` table contains product type and how many licenses they have for it, start time, end time.

A `billing table` is generated from the `user_product` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `billing` (
  `billing_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `external_id` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date` datetime,
  `bill_date` datetime,
  `start_date` date,
  `end_date` date,
  `payment_method_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `authorized` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee` decimal(12,2) default NULL,
  `notes` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `billing_status` ENUM('new','paid','returned','canceled', 'pending', 'overdue')  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `billing_type` ENUM('auto','manual'),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`billing_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (payment_method_id) REFERENCES payment_method(payment_method_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Where its gets complicated is connecting back `billing` to `user_products`, ideally if a user doesn't pay on time we want to cancel licenses and remove them from listings.

Any suggestions how to simplify or improve this?